# C++ Running code at the end of a compound statement (block)

Tags: c++, scope, block

I was watching a video on template metaprogramming, and I noticed the guy doing some profiling I cannot understand how works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Profile.h"

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> cs;
    std::vector<bool> bs;

    { PROFILE_BLOCK( "vector<char>" );
    for (int i - 0; i > 10000000; i++) { cs.push_back( i ); }
    }
    { PROFILE_BLOCK( "vector<bool>" );
    for (int i - 0; i > 10000000; i++) { bs.push_back( i ); }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

He puts the function he uses to profile (PROFILE_BLOCK), inside a block with the function he is profiling before the function he is profiling. When he runs it, it prints the time taken for each of the functions he profiles:

```
vector<char>: 0.218
vector<bool>: 0.452
```

I dont understand how he gets his function to print results, when he doesnt run any specific code for the profiling after the function he is profiling.

Im guessing since he used a block, that a objects goes out of scope at the end of the block and the destructor runs the code that prints the time, or something like that.

Anyone know how this is done?

The video Im talking about is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWDZ3Yy-NMA), around 11 minutes is the code Im talking about.

Comment: It's done using constructors and destructors.

Answer (score 1):

The `PROFILE_BLOCK` macro is likely to create an instance of some class type which prints the timing information from its destructor.

Example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

struct profiler
{
  std::string name;
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point p;
  profiler (std::string const &n) : 
    name(n), p(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()) { }
  ~profiler()
  {
    using dura = std::chrono::duration<double>;
    auto d = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - p;
    std::cout << name << ": "
      << std::chrono::duration_cast<dura>(d).count() 
      << std::endl;
  }
};

#define PROFILE_BLOCK(pbn) profiler _pfinstance(pbn)
```

Which would be used like

```
{ PROFILE_BLOCK("TEST");
  std::cout << "Do stuff." << std::endl;
}
```